# CSS background image disappears when float property is set to 'none'

Tags: css, css-float, background-image

I have a series of three boxes, each approximately one-third of the screen width. The first two boxes have widths of 33.333% and are floated left. I've removed the float on the third box and set the width to `auto` so that it fills the remaining horizontal space. However, doing so causes the background image to disappear. I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMwk9/) demonstrating this effect.

The HTML is very simple:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
div {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #EEE url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg/200px-Approve_icon.svg.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
 float: none;
 width: auto;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: hidden`:

```
div:nth-child(3) {
 float: none;
 width: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Without this directive the 3rd DIV is not filling the remaining space but overlapping the rest of the DIV's as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use `overflow: hidden` to solve this issue:

```
div:nth-child(3) {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The reason you don't get it is, when you give `width: auto`, they surely lose their `width`s for a `float`ed element.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/aMwk9/1/

Comment: +1 – Both answers were correct – it's hard to choose the 'right' answer. Thanks!

Comment: "when an element is float'ed, they lose their widths." what?

Comment: @xec They become `inline-block`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar and why would they lose their width? clearly the floats retain their 33%

Comment: @xec When you give `width: auto`, they surely lose their `width`s.

Comment: @PraveenKumar exactly, but that is not what your answer states. the floated divs did not lose their widths, the non-floated one did, but not because of being floated or not... I will remove the downvote if you revise the answer.